# How to add a label to axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts, legend

My graph is very similar to this example: http://jsfiddle.net/MrFox1/n6vwqafg/

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/us/us-all.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 410px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0
auto">
</div>

$(function () {

    $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=us-population-density.json&callback=?', function (data) {

        // Make codes uppercase to match the map data
        $.each(data, function () {
            this.code = this.code.toUpperCase();
        });

        // Instanciate the map
        Highcharts.mapChart('container', {

            chart: {
                borderWidth: 1
            },

            title: {
                text: 'US population density (/km²)'
            },

            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                borderWidth: 0,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.85)',
                floating: true,
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                align: 'right',
                y: 25
            },

            mapNavigation: {
                enabled: true
            },

            colorAxis: {
                min: 1,
                type: 'logarithmic',
                minColor: '#EEEEFF',
                maxColor: '#000022',
                stops: [
                    [0, '#EFEFFF'],
                    [0.67, '#4444FF'],
                    [1, '#000022']
                ]
            },

            series: [{
                animation: {
                    duration: 1000
                },
                data: data,
                mapData: Highcharts.maps['countries/us/us-all'],
                joinBy: ['postal-code', 'code'],
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                    format: '{point.code}'
                },
                name: 'Population density',
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{point.code}: {point.value}/km²'
                }
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

I need to add a label to the axis showing the average of all the data shown.
Ideally with a marker to the position in the legend. The same marker that is shown on the axis when you hover over the map, that shows how the color you're pointing to relates to the legend.

The average over all the numbers has already been calculated, it's just about how to show this visually.

Answer (score 0):

You can set tick positions in the color axis via `colorAxis.tickPositions` (array) or `colorAxis.tickPositioner` (callback). It will creates a tick for the specified value. If you use a logarithmic axis then those values need to be scaled properly.

```
colorAxis: {

  tickPositions: [Math.log10(1), Math.log10(10), Math.log10(calculatedAverage), Math.log10(100), Math.log10(1000)],
```

Then use `colorAxis.labels.formatter` to define text for a specific tick.

```
labels: {
            formatter: function () {
              return this.value == calculatedAverage 
                ? 'avg (' + this.value + ')'
                : this.value;
              }
            }
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/n6vwqafg/9/